# Inheriting a classes variable values in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have 3 classes and I have a method in my rectangle class that checks if the height and width are of the same length, however, if I set the height and width in my triangle class and inherit my triangle class it says that the rectangle isSquare() method is true because it is using the default values 0.0 and 0.0. How come it is not inheriting what I assigned in the Triangle class?

```
class inheritence {
    private double width;
    private double height;
    public void setHeight(double height){
        this.height=height;
    }
    public double getHeight(){
        return height;
    }
    public void setWidth(double width){
        this.width=width;
    }
    public double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    void showDim(){
        System.out.println("Width and height are "+width+" and "+height);
    }
}
```

---

```
class Triangle extends inheritence{
    String style;
    double area(){
        return getHeight()* getWidth();
    }
    void showStyle(){
        System.out.println("Triangle is "+style);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Rectangle extends Triangle{
    boolean isSquare(){
        if(getWidth()==getHeight()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public double area(){
        return getWidth()*getHeight();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Triangle t1=new Triangle();
        Triangle t2=new Triangle();
        Rectangle rect=new Rectangle();
        t1.setHeight(10);
        t1.setWidth(20);
        if(rect.isSquare()){
            System.out.println("Its a square!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Its not a square");
        }

        System.out.println(t1.getHeight());
        System.out.println(t1.getWidth());
        t1.showDim();
        System.out.println("The area for t1 is "+t1.area());
        t1.style="Outlined";
        t1.showStyle();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be true initially. Once you change the width and height properties, then it can be different. And a Rectangle is not a type of Triangle, so that's not a terribly good classing structure.

Comment: ... A rectangle is **definitely NOT** a triangle, so your inheritance structure is wrong to being with (and shape ones are traditionally problematic anyways).  Also, the area for a triangle would be wrong anyways.

Comment: Lol, I know it is terrible classing structure, BUT I am wondering why it wont work

Comment: The question is basically why cant I SAVE variable values in a class and then inherit those Values?

Comment: `inheritance` is a bad class name. 1) it should be capitalized. 2) it should be abstract 3) not all "shapes" are defined by a width and height... To address your problem, though, you extend classes, not instances, variables values are never "inherited" for non-static variables

Comment: @cricket_007 I am aware of that, its just practice lol and thank you that is what I was wondering

Comment: so I guess the way I would do this would be to call super() right?

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the `width` and `height` in an instance of your `Triangle` class (`t1`), but call the check `rect.isSquare()` on a different instance (which happens to be a `Rectangle`), for which you didn't set the `width` and `height`, so they remained 0.

The `width` and `height` members are instance members (they are not static), which means each instance of your `class inheritence` class would have different values for them, so setting them in one instance doesn't affect their values in other instances.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting height and width for the `t1` object instead of the `rect` object.
If you set it to rect object then the output will show `Its not a square`

```
    rect.setHeight(10);
    rect.setWidth(20);
```

Since you are inheriting values, you basically don't need separate triangle object instances to work with. You can work simply with 1 object i.e. `rect`

Comment: So for inheritance it wont inherit the values of the objects?

Comment: Since you are inheriting properties as per inheritance principle of OOPs, you basically don't need separate triangle object instances (`t1` or `t2`) to work with. You can work simply with 1 object i.e. (`rect`) Since `rect` is an object instance of `Rectangle`, it will inherit properties from `Triangle` and `Triangle` inturn, will inherit height and width from `inheritance` class.